# Issues with foreign keys when adding to database in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, wcf

I have a function (addItem) which is suppposed to add a new row to my database. But when the function runs, it gives me this error:

```
{"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK1\". The conflict occurred in database \"C:\\USERS\\ALAL0006\\DOWNLOADS\\SOA PROJEKT\\SOA PROJEKT\\SOA PROJEKT\\APP_DATA\\DATABASE1.MDF\", table \"dbo.Category\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categories = tbl.Category.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.Id).Trim(),
            Text = c.Namn
        });
        //ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(tbl.Category, "Id", "Namn");
        ViewBag.Id = categories;
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Vara newItm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            srvc.addItem(newItm.Namn, newItm.Pris, newItm.CategoryID);
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Service:

```
public void addItem(string name, int price, int ctgID)
    {
        Database1Entities1 tbl = new Database1Entities1();
        Vara newItm = new Vara() {

            Namn = name,
            Pris = price,
            CategoryID = ctgID,

        };
        tbl.Vara.Add(newItm);
        try
        {
            tbl.SaveChanges();
        }
```

cshtml file:

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Namn, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Namn)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Namn)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pris, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pris)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pris)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryID, "CategoryID", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Id", "Välj kategori")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Category DB:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category] (
[Id]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Namn] VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));
```

Item DB:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Vara] (
[Id]         INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Namn]       VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Pris]       INT           NOT NULL,
[CategoryID] INT           NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK1] FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] ([Id]));
```

I am unsure of what I am supposed to do to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: Check catID exist in category table as primary key.

Comment: @Zaki It does exist, has the name "Id" in the Category table and it is the primary key.

Comment: Thank you very much @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in the POST method, the value of `newItm.CategoryID` is `0` (the default for `int`) because you never generate a form control for property `CategoryID` (the `<select>` element you generating is for property `Id`).

You need to change the code in your view to (always use the strongly typed `xxxFor()` methods)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Id, "Välj kategori")
```

In addition, you need to modify your POST method to reassign the value of `ViewBag.Id` if `ModelState` is invalid and you return the view, otherwise an exception will be thrown

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Vara newItm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ....
    }
    ViewBag.Id = ... // same code as used in the GET method.
    return View(newItm);
}
```

However a better approach is to use view models (refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)).

```
public class VaraVM
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    ....
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a category")]
    public int SelectedCategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectistItem> CategoryList { get; set; }   
}
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategory , Model.CategoryList, "Välj kategori")
```

and in the controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    VaraVM model = new VaraVM();
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(VaraVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);  
    }
    // map the view model to a new instance of the data model
    // save and redirect
}

private void ConfigureViewModel(VaraVM model)
{
    model.CategoryList = .... // your query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have empty model.CategoryID in

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID)
```

because you stored list of categories to ViewBag.Id and showed View with empty model:

```
 ViewBag.Id = categories;
 return View();
```

Your post is generated with ctgID = 0 (default value of integer).
In save step to database via EntityFramework your insert probably failed, because your Category table hasn't row with Id = 0. (default first row Id in MSSQL is 1)

Answer (score -1):

You send Vara object CategoryID, because CategoryID Foreign key in Category table,
Category table have been you send CategoryID

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you are saying and not enough detail.